# Reading Current FAA ADs via API

Tags: data-request, api, aviation

Is anyone aware of a way to query/download Airworthiness Directives? I don't want to resort to HTML scraping, but I can't seem to find any alternatives.

I wouldn't be opposed to downloading whole chunks of the data and parsing it locally, but I don't even see a great way to do that.

Any help would be appreciated!

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Best I've found is getting them [via email](https://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgSAIB.nsf/MainFrame?OpenFrameSet). It doesn't seem like there is any [explicit demand via CFR](https://ecfr.report/t/title-14-aeronautics-and-space-volume-1/#393_Definition_of_airworthiness_directives) to make the data available via API.